# 3D Stereoscopic with nVidia

Tags: nvidia, 3d

I have a 3D compatible tv (over HDMI) and a nVidia GTX660 (should be 3D compatible and has a HDMI port). Can I make things in 3D? (Watch a movie in mkv, playMinecraft with stereoscopic  MOD...)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need at least HDMI Version 1.4, taken from here: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Definition_Multimedia_Interface

I would be eager to test mp4 "Big Buck Bunny 3D" with Bino3D or 3Dtv, available here: [BBB 3D](http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net/download.html)